# How to get oldest record in mongodb group in side the grouped record?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have set of records and try to get unique record for each row and unique record is the group, query is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    $match : { 
        userId: 16,
        userListId : ObjectId('5b7e85f956de7e6ead026e23') ,

    } 
},
{
    $group: 
    {
        _id: '$domain',
        "websites": { $push: {
            '_id' : '$_id',
            'userId' : '$userId',
            'userListId' : "$userListId",
            'createdAt' : '$createdAt'
        }}
    }
}
```

]);

For the same domain i have 4 rows which are

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7e55bb0f81ba2c5b0b54c8"),
        "userId" : 16,
        "userListId" : ObjectId("5b7e85f956de7e6ead026e23"),
        "createdAt" : 1535006139565.0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7e55bb0f81ba2c5b0b54a9"),
        "userId" : 16,
        "userListId" : ObjectId("5b7e85f956de7e6ead026e23"),
        "createdAt" : 1535006139564.0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7e55bb0f81ba2c5b0b54b4"),
        "userId" : 16,
        "userListId" : ObjectId("5b7e85f956de7e6ead026e23"),
        "createdAt" : 1535006139565.0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7e55bb0f81ba2c5b0b54c4"),
        "userId" : 16,
        "userListId" : ObjectId("5b7e85f956de7e6ead026e23"),
        "createdAt" : 1535006139565.0
    }
```

In the above records second record is first one from the database and i want to get it on first position, how can i do that?

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b7e55bb0f81ba2c5b0b54a9")
```

I want above record on first position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply begin your pipeline the $sort operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 16,
      userListId: ObjectId("5b7e85f956de7e6ead026e23"),

    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "createdAt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$domain",
      "websites": {
        $push: {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "userId": "$userId",
          "userListId": "$userListId",
          "createdAt": "$createdAt"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ycBrrtRM002)

**Note**: Updated as per @chridam suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: For better performance I would suggest you move the `$match` pipeline as the first to minimize the number of objects to sort, `$sort` then `$group`. By default mongo does this for you with a pipeline optimizer but optimizations are subject to change between releases so it's good practice to see how the optimizer transforms a particular aggregation pipeline by including the [`explain`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option in the `db.collection.aggregate()` method.

Comment: Agreed. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @sandy you are welcome. If you thing this solves your problem please mark it as the answer so other people can find it easier etc.

Comment: You want to sort all records by `createdAt` field?